# compile is deprecated replace with implementation

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.5.3

I have just update my android studio to the last version which is 3.3.5 but am really stuck with this problem
`Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:` 
whene tring to add apdf view to my project. knowing that i already have the last version of gradle too . but still it is showing that i should update my grable.

```
The project 'test' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.3 and sync project
```

'''

```
The project 'test' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

i think it is because the of the source starting by compile but how can i replace it.

Comment: Can you post your project build.gradle file?

Comment: Add your module level `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

To update Gradle plugin to 3.5.3:

In your top-level **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    //...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        //...
    }
}
```

To fix the error with *compile()* method:

In your module-level **build.gradle** replace *compile()* with *implementation()* as follows:

```
compile 'com.somelibrary:somelibrary:1.0'
// with
implementation 'com.somelibrary:somelibrary:1.0'

testCompile 'com.sometestlibrary:sometestlibrary:1.0'
// with
testImplementation 'com.sometestlibrary:sometestlibrary:1.0'
```

Comment: that was very helpfull thank you sir.   I actualy  mae a mistake instead of replacing the url in grable.build all module i replace it in the grable.buildapp .

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle plugin as well as gradle wrapper version as stated in the URL
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin